# websocket 301 using domain but not using ip direcly

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, dns

I run a simple websocket using

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
```

when I try to connect to the server using

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://84.***.***.***:8080') // my ip adress
```

everything works fine, no error, the connection event gets triggered and I can send a message.
If I use my domain though, i.e.

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://sub.example.com:8080')
```

I get this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://sub.example.com:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
```

I am using an A record to point the subdomain to my actual domain (using cloudflair, *imported* from namecheap).
Wikipedia tells me

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for permanent redirecting, meaning current links or records using the URL this response is received for should be updated.

Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a server issue rather than a code issue, I'm not an expert but my understanding is this:

Arecord points a name to an ip, so the browser hits the name and is then redirected to the ip that the websocket server is on.

ws can't/won't follow redirects, at least not out of the box

I would suggest simply using the ip instead of name, as it will save you a lot of trouble

Comment: I fixed it by disabling the CloudFlare proxy for this subdomain, but thank you for your answer

Comment: if you fixed the issue then create an answer so other people can find it easier

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by disabling the CloudFlare proxy for this subdomain